# Qt mouse hover over GUI causes QThread loop to freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, events, qthread

I am newbie and ran into some problem.
I am reading traffic in one QThread, make calculations in other QThread and output data in QTableWidget in GUI. When I'm do nothing, it works very well, but when I'm hover mouse over GUI, reader thread starts to freeze and loose traffic.
How to avoid that freezing and why GUI affects other thread?

Reader read method:

```
void FrameReader::read()
{
    int res = pcap_next_ex(m_adhandle, &m_currentFrame->header, &m_currentFrame->pkt_data);
    if (res > 0)
    {
        frame_dst = readMAC(m_currentFrame->pkt_data, 0x0, 6).value<MAC>();
        if (frame_dst.m1 != 0x01 && frame_dst.m2 != 0x0c && frame_dst.m3 != 0xcd) qDebug() << "Wrong frame data";
        bool filter = (m_dst != nullptr) ? ((frame_dst == *m_dst) ? true : false) : true;
        if (filter)
        {
            emit frameReceived(m_currentFrame);                
        }
    }
    else if (res == -1)
    {
        qDebug() << "Frame read error";
    }
    if (isOn) QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "read", Qt::QueuedConnection);

}
```

It emits frameReceived signal, that is connected to all necessary calculation classes methods in calculation thread through QueuedConnection.

After calculations calculation class emits valuesIsReady signal, that is connected through QueuedConnection to GUI widget, and that widget outputs calculated data simply taking data from variables in calculation class.

Reader and calculation classes have wrapping worker classes, which are transferred in their individual QThreads via moveToThread().

It works without mouse moving, but when I'm hover mouse over GUI, some troubles happen.

Comment: Is this your mouseover code? Or could you be tying up the main execution thread somehow?

Comment: Yes, I found mistake. I left group of objects tied up to main thread, when I initialized them. After moving to correct thread all works very well.